# Eclipse Neon running GAE is incredibly slow to refresh

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-plugin-eclipse

I have just deployed Eclipse Neon in a Windows 7 environment (coming from many years of using Netbeans) and the Google (java) App Engine environment (as Google instructs and all works).

Using the standard gae 'hello world' example, when I make a change to the text on the sample 'Hello App Engine Standard' .jsp, for example changing that text to 'Hello hello', I have two issues:

1. In Eclipse I have to save and then hit F5 to refresh. Is there any way that Eclipse can auto-refresh on save like Netbeans does?
2. After saving and hitting F5 I then need to reload my browser 4-5 times before the trivial change shows up. Netbeans does it instantly. Does anyone have any idea where I start looking as Eclipse is totally new to me or is this just the way Eclipse works?

Thanks

Comment: It is not how GAE works in a Netbeans environment, it is very fast. But that is a red herring. The two questions relate to to the Eclipse Neon environment. Is it really a slow IDE or am I not setting something right. Is there anyone who has used this environment (Eclipse + GAE) who can offer me any guidance or any settings to adjust?

Comment: Do you run the application locally or deployed to App Engine?

Comment: Also can you clarify which Eclipse plugin do you use? Is it the Google Plugin for Eclipse or the newer Cloud Tools for Eclipse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the Cloud Tools for Eclipse plugin, you can set the publishing delay on the server as follows:

Double click on the local devappserver in the Servers view:

[image: Servers view]

In the editor that opens up set the publishing interval to 0 seconds:

[image]

Comment: Andras Kerekes, I use the Cloud Tools for Eclipse plugin. I did as you suggest and set the Publishing interval to 0 and...  INSTANT UPDATING, just as I would have hoped. Thank you very much for providing the answer, it is a massive relief. Maybe Google could add it to their documentation. Thank you, thank you, thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

I had previously done some work in java GAE. Eclipse was pretty terrible frankly ended up switching to intellij. Shortly after I ended up switching to python for it. I use pycharm from the same company, you need the pro edition sadly, also here is a great lib [for it](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-proto-datastore/tree/master/endpoints_proto_datastore) supposedly it runs fairly similarly in terms of speed in GAE compared to java. Also endpoints will generate client code for you with little work.

Comment: Thank you for that. I did look at Intellij and GAE but the deploy process looked terrible and still in beta. But Eclipse taking so long to run  a refresh is just not sustainable so I might have to try Intellij.

Comment: I run into an issue commonly when i break GAE several times over. That it basically won't restart and I have to restart my computer. I can't remember how it works in Eclipse but in pycharm my code runs live(I think this is because of python though) so I try just to not close it. Honestly though python really is the way to go. I've accomplished more in a few days in it then i did in 3+ months in java.